# Facebook api login error - not redirecting to facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

Error screenshot at: http://s3.postimg.org/hsi4j8jz7/wefwer.jpg

I am getting this error when i press the login button. I'm not redirection to facebook for authentication.

login.php file:

```
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'xxxx',
  'app_secret' => 'xxxx',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = ['publish_actions']; // Optional permissions
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://distroapps1.vserver.cz/fb-callback.php', $permissions);

echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($loginUrl) . '">Log in with Facebook!       </a>';
?>
```

fb-callback.php:

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'xxxx',
  'app_secret' => 'xxxx',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (! isset($accessToken)) {
  if ($helper->getError()) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
    echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
    echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
    echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
  } else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
    echo 'Bad request';
  }
  exit;
}

// Logged in
echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
var_dump($accessToken->getValue());

// The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

// Get the access token metadata from /debug_token
$tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
echo '<h3>Metadata</h3>';
var_dump($tokenMetadata);

// Validation (these will throw FacebookSDKException's when they fail)
$tokenMetadata->validateAppId($config['app_id']);
// If you know the user ID this access token belongs to, you can validate it here
//$tokenMetadata->validateUserId('123');
$tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();

if (! $accessToken->isLongLived()) {
  // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
  try {
    $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
  } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $helper->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
    exit;
  }

  echo '<h3>Long-lived</h3>';
  var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
}

$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

// User is logged in with a long-lived access token.
// You can redirect them to a members-only page.
//header('Location: https://example.com/members.php');

?>
```

Comment: The output suggest that you _have_ an access token at that point already – so there is no need to show the login dialog to the user _again_.

Comment: @CBroe But I've made another script with `<?php session_destroy ?>` to logout but still the same error. Also i've moved the site to another hosting and it's not working too! i changed the site in fb app page too. And if i give the wrong link in fb app page, it redirects but shows error.

Comment: @CBroe btw, I'm using a subdomain, does that matter?

Comment: Again: What your current screenshot shows, is not an “error”. If it is not _behaving_ as you want it to – well, then be more specific as to what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: @CBroe I found the error, it was not here, it was at my photo posting page, i forget to edit the token variable there `$_SESSION['facebook_access_token']`. Thank you for your help :D.. btw, I'm new to this site, should i keep this question here for others? or should i delete this?